# Is it me or the relay info websites?

Tags: relays, bandwidth, atlas

I got my relay working just fine, torrc is all configured to my liking, etc. But when I checked Atlas and Globe to see the bandwidth differences between when I went to bed last night and when I got up this morning, the graph for the bandwidth is exactly the same as I went to bed last night, and the graph has a large white space with no data in it, like it's not updating. So my question is, did I break something, or is it just delayed that much between updating?

It's worth noting that it has been roughly 12 hours between when I checked before I went to bed, and when I checked when I got up. And the "Weights" graph on Globe and Atlas have been updating normally, giving me information about the probability for the usage of my exit node, etc.

Also, when I check out any logs for errors, there is nothing wrong with Tor. It restarts a few times, gives me info about how much data it has sent and received, but no major errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your relay a new relay or a relatively new one? If yes, that behavior is normal. New relays need few days before they start functioning as real relays. For more details about a relay lifecycle, [this article](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay) is an excellent read.

Comment: This completely answered any questions I had about what the heck was happening to my relay. Thank you so much!